# WinSCP Command line - Adding known hosts

Tags: ssh, md5, sftp, winscp

I have windows batch script which connect to a server for fetching the transaction files.

The program uses Winscp command line scripting to open sftp connection and fetch the required files.

Recently the provider asked to update the known hosts and provided fingerprints in MD5,SHA 256, Bubble Babble options. I would like to continue executing the program in passive mode without any manual intervention on prompts.

With my limited knowledge in this, I understand adding an additional parameter with -hostkey will solve the issue. But I'm not not whether I need to add any additional parameter to specify whether it is MD5 or SHA etc. Any help is appreciated.

Current code:

```
open sftp://%USERNAME%@%HOSTNAME%
```

Planning to update to

```
open sftp://%USERNAME%@%HOSTNAME% -hostkey="<key>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not specify the fingerprint algorithm. Just specify the fingerprint using one of the format that WinSCP understands.

The [`-hostkey` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey) supports two formats:

- MD5: `keytype bits fi:ng:er:pr:in:t`
- SHA-256: `keytype bits fingerprint=`

For example:

- `ssh-dss 2048 0b:77:8b:68:f4:45:b1:3c:87:ad:5c:be:3b:c5:72:78`
- `ssh-ed25519 256 D+O+VGvZhUStHQL82ph5ogOWnP7Dvn+XsFie47+1Jr0=`

---

*SHA-256 is supported by recent versions of WinSCP only.*

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will execute this and let you know.

Comment: Additionally, If I accept hostkey/fingerprint in WinSCP GUI mode, do I still need to pass hostkey when I connect to same server from same machine using command line?

Comment: If you share a configuration between GUI and the script, you do not have to use the `-hostkey` switch, if you have already accepted the host key in GUI (and **really verified that it matches** the fingerprint from provider) - But it's not recommended: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#configuration

Comment: @PrasanthPillai You should be honored to have no less than "The author of WinSCP" answer your questions. Why did you not accept the answer?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, I was waiting for the banks to confirm the transactions and so far no errors reported, which looks it worked perfectly.